# Why am I getting incorrect time format from CultureInfo?

Tags: c#, globalization, datetime-format

I have to display a current time on my application during certain operations, if current system time format is `HH:mm:ss` then if user change it to `hh:mm:ss tt` when app is still running it does not pick up the changes! It still displays time in `HH:mm:ss`.

I tried using `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()` and `DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);`

Is there anything missing? Any suggestions to fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the framework is simply caching the pattern used for the time format, and won't normally pick it up again until you restart the app.

You could try calling [`ClearCachedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clearcacheddata.aspx) and see if it then goes back to the OS for the system time format. (I don't know whether there's anything you can monitor to work out *when* the format has changed - you don't want to be clearing the cache all the time, of course.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, `ClearCacheData` does solve the problem, however, as you said I need to figure out when to clear the cache.

Comment: If you are able to listen to window messages, then listening for WM_SETTINGCHANGE will tell you when you need to clear the cache.